# Want to know how to "reveal" a "hidden" string ( formatted like ****)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

So i want to create a kind of game.

First I have a word (string) that the user has to guess.

For example if we have the word "Code", it has to be formatted in the beginning like this "****" and the user has to guess the word.

I have the following code :

```
char hidden_word[ ] = "CODE";
char word2[ ] = "CODE";
char user_character = 0;

do 
  {
    printf("\nThe hidden word is : %s ", strset(hidden_word, '*') );
    printf("\nTry to guess it : ");

    user_character = read_char(); /// i created the read_char() function, it reads the input and automatically "UPPERCASE" it

  } while ( strchr (word2, user_character) == NULL );
```

This works perfectly.
But my problem is that I don't know how to "reveal" the "hidden_word" depending on the user's input.
For example if the user inputs "O" the program should say

```
"Nice try, the hidden word is now *O**"
```

Help is needed. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Try using a loop to see if you can find each occurrence of a given character (the user input) in a string.

Comment: Change `char hidden_word[ ] = "CODE";` to `char hidden_word[ ] = "****";` and replace the stars with letters from `word2` when correct guesses are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strchr` returns a pointer to the first occurrence in the string of the character searched for. If `strchr` returned non-`NULL`, you can get the index of the found character with:

```
char *p = strchr(str, 'x');
if(p)
{
    ptrdiff_t pos = (ptrdiff_t)(p - str);
}
```

Then, have a second mutable string, say, `str2`, that's the same length of your word, initially populated only with `*`s, and each time a letter is found:

```
str2[pos] = found_character;
```

Comment: But can you tell me more about the use of ptrdiff_t ? It"s my first time seeing it. I was looking for a way to know the index of the correct-guessed word and i guess that "ptrdiff_t" will do the work

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is an appropriate type for obtaining the difference (i.e. distance) between two pointers. It is documented in [§ 7.19p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p2) of the C standard.

If you use `(ptrdiff_t)(str - i)` (where `i` was returned from `strchr(str, ...)`), you will have the correct index in `str` to write to where the sought character was found.

Comment: Oh Okay thanks, i got it now. I tried it and it's working but in my case i did ( ptrdiff_t ) ( i - str ) instead of ( str - i ) to get the correct index. Thank you !

Comment: @TonyStark Because of your comment I just realized the correct operation is `p - str`, not `str - p`. I'll update my post shortly.

Comment: Yes that is the correct operation. I saw the update everything perfect now

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems with your current code.

1. You use `strset` within the loop so you will keep setting the hidden word back to all `*`
2. Your condition to end the loop is wrong
3. You need an extra loop to turn the `*` into a correct letter

Fixing that could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char correct_word[ ] = "CODE";
    char hidden_word[ ] = "****";
    char user_character;

    do 
    {
        printf("\nThe hidden word is : %s ", hidden_word );
        printf("\nTry to guess it : ");

        user_character = getchar();

        // Check for guessed characters
        int i = 0;
        while(correct_word[i])
        {
            if (correct_word[i] == user_character) hidden_word[i] = correct_word[i];
            ++i;
        }
    } while ( strchr (hidden_word, '*') != NULL );  // Check for * in the hidden word

    printf("\nThe hidden word is : %s ", hidden_word );

    return 0;
}
```